# Why does Java string have a copy constructor?

Tags: java, string

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the purpose of the expression “new String(…)” in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/390703/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-expression-new-string-in-java)

It's immutable, why would you need to invoke [`String.String(String str)`](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.3/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#String(java.lang.String)) ?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/334518/java-strings-string-s-new-stringsilly ?

Comment: Dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/390703/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-expression-new-string-in-java, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/465627/use-of-the-stringstring-constructor-in-java

Answer (score 3, accepted):

new String(s) can help garbase collection:

```
String huge = ...;
String small = s.substring(0,2); //huge.value char[] is not garbage collected here
String gcFriendly = new String(small); //now huge.value char[] can be garbage collected
```

Comment: How does that help garbage collection?  One would end up with *more* garbage this way.

Comment: It helps garbage collection if you allow huge and small to go out of scope as gcFriendly does not reference the very large char[] that backs both huge and small.

Comment: Accepted this and not the more detailed answer simply because of the code sample.

Answer (score 15):

From the API doc:

```
Unless an explicit copy of original is needed, use of this constructor is
unnecessary since Strings are immutable.
```

The only reason I can think of is in the situation where:

1. You've created a very large `String`: A.
2. You've created a small substring: B based on A.  If you look at the implementation of `substring` you'll see it references the **same char[] array** as the original string.
3. `String` A has gone out of scope and you **wish to reduce memory consumption**.
4. Creating an explicit copy of B will mean that the copy: B' no longer references the large `char[]`.  Allowing B to go out of scope will allow the garbage collector to reclaim the large `char[]` that backs A and B, leaving only the small `char[]` backing B'.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case you need String that are not the same but equal.

Maybe for testing to make sure, people really do `str.equals(str2)` instead of `(str == str2)`. But I never needed it.