# About the keyword, "new" in Java

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Questions about Java's String pool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1881922/questions-about-javas-string-pool)

Guys what is the difference between these two.

(1)

```
String s = new String("hello"); // creating an object on heap then assign that object to the reference s.
```

(2)

```
String s = "hello" // did I make an object here?? Im not using the word new.
```

Also array example

```
int x[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}; // did I make object here?
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Yes you have created a new string obj
2. "hello" may be in the heap but its not really in the heap. And it's not created / allocated at runtime Instead, it is interned before your program gets going.
3. Yes you created an int[] in the heap

Answer (score 4):

`String s = "hello"` is assigning the [**string literal**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_literal) "hello" to `s`

Using the `new` keyword, you create a new object, in addition to the string literal.

note that:

```
String s = "hello";
System.out.println(s == "hello");
s = new String("hello");
System.out.println(s == "hello");
```

will most likely yield

```
true
false
```

Since `s` is referncing the string literal "hello" - you got an identity in the first case, while in the second it's a new object, and there is no identity - those are two different objects, that happen to contain the same value.

Regarding your array question: yes, an `int[]` object is created.

Comment: Just as a note, the String literal is a source-code representation of a pre-defined String object.  So using the new keyword, you are actually making a *copy* of an existing String object.  So you end up with 2 String objects instead of one.

Comment: so String s = "hello" didnt create a new object?? I thought in java everthing is an object??

Comment: @user1293258: It is an object, it is just a *string literal*. the jvm maintains a *pool* of string literals, and reuses the same object. So, in the assiment `s = "hello"` and when later comparing `s` to `"hello"`, the same string literal is used - which is the same object. And regarding: `I thought in java everthing is an object` - it is not true. `int`, `boolean` [and all other *primitive types*] are **not** objects.

Comment: how about this? String o = new String("hello"); then o == "hello" the answer will be false, why is it becuase string literal "hello" has a null character as a last character?

Comment: @user1293258: `new String("hello)` creates a new object. In java, `operator==` checks for *identity* and not *equality* - it checks if the two objects are the same object ["occupies the same space in memory"]. `new String("hello")` is located in a new place in memory, other then the one of the string literal, thus they are not the same objects and the result is `false` as expected.

Comment: what uses the hashcode to compare? == or equals() ?

Comment: @user1293258: `hashCode()` does not compare objects, it generates int from a single object. If you mean how we compare two hash-codes of two different objects - we do it with `operator==` since the value returned by `hashCode()` is an `int` which is not an object. To check *equality* of two objects, we use `equals()`.

Comment: does the string literal object also have hashcode? is it the reason why o == "hello" is false?

Comment: @user1293258: It has nothing to do with `hashCode()`. `"hello".hashCode() == new String("hello").hashCode()`. But this is a different discussion entirely.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding string constructor, you have always objects.

when you say

```
String test = "test";
```

you create one string object with content "test", but when you say

```
String test= new String("test");
```

you create one string object with content "test" and pass it as argument to the string
constructor to create a new String object. So finally you had
created 2 string objects.

The code of the constructor is:

```
public String(String original){.....}
```

The string constructor is consider useless in most of the cases.

In this thread they described when it can be used

[Use of the String(String) constructor in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/465627/use-of-the-stringstring-constructor-in-java)