# About string concatenation behaviours

Tags: java, string, stringbuilder, string-pool

I understand that, given the immutability of strings, something like

```
String a="";
for(int i=0;i++<9;)
    a+=i;
```

is highly inefficient, because initially a string is instantiated and put in the *string pool*, then with `a+=i` a new string is created (*0* in the first loop), referenced by `a` and the previous one is now eligible for garbage collection. And this happens nine times.

A better way is using `StringBuilder`:

```
StringBuilder a=new StringBuilder("");
for(int i=0;i++<9;)
    a.append(i);
```

But what happens behind the scenes when I instantiate the string with the
`new` keyword?

```
String a=new String("");
for(int i=0;i++<9;)
    a+=i;
```

I know that in this case `a` doesn't get interned (it's not in the string pool), but is it still immutable? What does the `a+=i` instruction do in this time? Is the behaviour identical to my first example?

Comment: What makes you think that all the strings are put in the pool in your first version? Only the empty string would be in the string pool... the rest would just be on the heap. And yes, all strings are immutable, regardless of whether they come from the constant pool or not.

Comment: @JonSkeet thanks for clarification... I'm a bit confused

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Only `String` **literals**, or `Strings` you call the `intern()` method on are put in the String pool. Concatenation does not automagically intern a `String`, so your examples will be identical with regards to the String pool.

```
String abc = new String("abc"); //"abc" is put on the pool
abc += "def"; //"def" is put on the pool, but "abcdef" is not
String xyz = "abcdefghi".substring(0, 6).intern(); //"abcdef" is now added to the pool and returned by the intern() function
String xyz = "test"; //test is put on the pool
xyz += "ing"; //ing is put on the pool, but "testing" is not
```

And to expand on this, note that the String constructor does not intern (or **not** intern) a String automatically. The use of String **literals** (Strings in quotation marks in your code) is what causes the String to be on the String pool.

```
String abc = "abc"; //"abc" is in the pool
String def = "def"; //"def" is in the pool
String str1 = new String(abc + def); //"abcdef" is not in the pool yet
String str2 = new String("abcdef"); //"abcdef" is on the pool now
```

Also note that the `String` copy constructor is almost never used, since Strings are immutable anyway.

For more info, read the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/390703/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-expression-new-string-in-java), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/465627/use-of-the-stringstring-constructor-in-java), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13803505/why-string-class-has-copy-constructor).

Comment: Clear! I thought there was a connection between the process of interning a string and its immutability

Comment: `String abc = new String("abc");` goes to the pool?? My book disagrees, or I'm really confused...

Comment: The String "abc" is a String **literal**, so yes, it goes on the pool. The constructor does not automagically intern (or **not** intern) a String.

Comment: So, what you mean is that the literal `"abc"` goes to the pool, but the variable `abc` doesn't?

Comment: @LuigiCortese I'm not sure what you're asking. Variables themselves are never interned, so it's a bit of a non-question. I've edited my answer to include information about the constructor.

Comment: by reading answers like these http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1881922/questions-about-javas-string-pool i thought that `new String("abc");` was not going to put `"abc"` in the pool...

Comment: @LuigiCortese The String literal "abc" is put in the pool. The String returned by the constructor is a copy of that String.

Comment: OK, that's what I meant by *the literal goes to the pool but the variable doesn't*, but said very poorly =)

Answer (score 3):

Let's consider your first example:

```
String a="";
for(int i=0;i++<9;)
    a+=i;
```

This code will be executed like this:

```
String a="";
a=new StringBuilder(a).append(0).toString();
a=new StringBuilder(a).append(1).toString();
a=new StringBuilder(a).append(2).toString();
a=new StringBuilder(a).append(3).toString();
a=new StringBuilder(a).append(4).toString();
a=new StringBuilder(a).append(5).toString();
a=new StringBuilder(a).append(6).toString();
a=new StringBuilder(a).append(7).toString();
a=new StringBuilder(a).append(8).toString();
a=new StringBuilder(a).append(9).toString();
```

So for each cycle iteration you will have a new `StringBuilder` created from the string (every time a new internal `char[]` buffer is allocated) which would be converted back to `String` every time. On the other hand in the second case you will effectively have

```
StringBuilder a=new StringBuilder("").append(0).append(1).append(2).append(3)
    .append(4).append(5).append(6).append(7).append(8).append(9);
```

So you will have only one `StringBuilder` with only one internal `char[]` buffer (it will not be reallocated in your case as all the appendings don't exceed the initial capacity of `16`). So it's simply faster, because you have less objects and nothing is copied multiple times.

Writing `a=new String("")` is useless as you will have one more empty string in addition to empty string you already have (which is created and interned during the loading of your class constant pool). Aside from additional empty string (which will become unused after the first loop iteration and garbage collected) it does not differ from the first case.

Please note that it's not specified exactly in JLS how string concatenation is implemented (using implicit `StringBuilder` or some other technique), but usually java compilers translate it using `StringBuilder`.