# What is the advantage of using new String("String") constructor if the literals in java are never garbage collected

Tags: java, string, garbage-collection, string-literals

[What is the purpose of the expression "new String(...)" in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/390703/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-expression-new-string-in-java)

In short the problem is to create a substring from a huge string 
so the author argues that it is better to use the new String(substring) constructor because string returned by substring() will use the same char[] as parent string, so if we do not use new String() then the huge literal will still be in use.
in order to avoid unnecessary huge char[] occupying memory it is better to create new String object with smaller char[] and hence shorter literal.
the huge char[] can then be garbage collected 
But!
as I learned literal are never garbage collected!

[Garbage collection of String literals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15324143/garbage-collection-of-string-literals)

So even though huge char[] is not pointed by any local variable it can still stay in the literal pool hence defeats the purpose of efficiently using memory.

Comment: That is outdated. `substring` no longer shares underlying arrays (unless it was a no-op).

Comment: See [Use of the String(String) constructor in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/465627/use-of-the-stringstring-constructor-in-java).

Comment: And http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13803505/why-string-class-has-copy-constructor?lq=1

Comment: ok! I learned as of java 7 created new char[] for substring.
but then it totally eliminates need of new String() constructor, doesn't it?

Comment: String literals in java can be GCed if the classloader which loaded the class which defined these literals is GCed.

Comment: This question (if we consider it a question, as there are only statements) seems to assume that `substring` is always invoked an a literal. Just consider that you could invoke `substring` on a `String` instance that is *not* a literal, so the behavior of literals is not relevant then. Yes, starting with jdk7u6, this constructor becomes (even) less relevant, but existing constructors can’t be removed at will. Maybe [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40726930/2711488) helps…